# Center background image to fit any monitor

Tags: jquery, image, background

I have two background images that scroll automatically with Jquery using setTimeout and both images are 1920x1080 pixels. While building the site I was working on a monitor that was that exact size and never realized that when viewing the site on a laptop for example, the images get cut off.

I would like that the image always be centered no matter what screen size the user has. Right now if someone has a monitor of 1200 pixels wide, it's only showing the first 1200 pixels of the image in width. I tried using "background-position: center" but it only broke my jquery code.

I should also mention that the following Jquery code works fine, I just can't add in a property that makes the background always centered to the users computer.

```
$(function () {
var body = $('body');
var backgrounds = new Array(
   'url(images/hso-evening-boardwalk-background.jpg)',
   'url(images/hso-palmtree-background.jpg)' 
);


var current = 0;

function nextBackground() {
    var bckg = backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length];
    var tmpDIV = $('<div/>', {
        id: "tmpDIV"
    }).prependTo('body').hide().css({
        position: "absolute",
        zIndex:-1,
        top:0,
        left:0,
        height: $(window).height(),
        width: $(window).width(),
        background: bckg
    }).fadeIn( 1500, function () {
        body.css('background',bckg);
        $(this).remove();
    });


    setTimeout(nextBackground, 8000);

}
setTimeout(nextBackground, 8000);
body.css('background', backgrounds[0]);
});
```

Comment: Look at the `background-size: cover;` css styling

Comment: No that doesn't work. It seems any sort of css styling I add to my current code breaks it...